# Query results from table

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am writing a script to query what edition of Windows machines are on. So far I have the following code:

```
    $ASSETNUM = Read-Host "Please enter a valid asset tag"

Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ASSETNUM | select PSComputerName, Caption, OSArchitecture, Version, BuildNumber | FL

if (Caption = "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise"){
    Write-Host "This works"
    } else {
    Write-Host "This did not work"
    }
```

The first part before the if statement works as intended. However, I wish to query the "Caption" to be able to run a further function afterwards. However, I'm at a loss on how to query this. The Write-Host parts are just for testing until I get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `| FL` because that is only to *display* stuff onto the screen.
Instead, capture the output in a variable and use that

```
$os = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ASSETNUM | Select-Object PSComputerName, Caption, OSArchitecture, Version, BuildNumber
```

Next, use the `$os` variable to get the property you need, in this case you want

```
if ($os.Caption -eq "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise"){
    Write-Host "This works"
} 
else {
    Write-Host "This did not work"
}
```

<sup>P.S. The `=` is an assignment, in case you want to compare something inside an `if()`, you need to use PowerShell's [comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) `-eq`</sup>